# Can not get the results in Web project due to error in XML

Tags: xml

"HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" is occuring while running the Web Project.I have created an HTML file, a Servlet and for processing this i have provided an XML file.I feel there is some error with the XML file.

A) index.html

```
<form action="add">
```

B) Demo.java
......

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
int j=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));
int k=i + j;
PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
out.println("Result is " +k);
```

......

C) Web.xml
.....

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Demo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

.....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested, that shows the error message you get.

Comment: Can you post the entire codes for index.html and xml.  Because you might be missing something or spelling or a tag. Also how are you passing your xml file to html. Do you have an xslt file and if you a writing a java code do you have java xpath file?

Comment: Thanks all, It has been resolved. This was occurring due to  the xml file which was created manually. Whereas, it should have been generated by the Deployment Descriptor.